# React router can't find page after page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, routes, react-router

My App is displaying a list of books with links to a detail page about the book.

When I am on the home component where the book list is rendered and click on a link to get to a specific book, the page is loading correctly...

But when I refresh the page, there is a 404 - Page not found error

(I'm using react-router v4, Node v6.11.1, Express v4.15.2)

**React Router setup:**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router  } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyNavbar/>
                <div style={{paddingTop: "5rem"}}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                        <Route path='/book/:id' component={BookPage}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

**This is my webpack config:**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'public/dist/bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'public/dist/bundle.map.js'
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=200000&name=./imgs/[hash].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: I guess you are using browserRouter, is it?

Comment: Some news about server you are using?

Comment: yes @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: I'm not using webpack-dev-server but nodemon, could that be the problem? @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: are you using webpack??? Do read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually/36623117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the [doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback)~

if you are use `webpack-dev-server`

1. if you write the `webpack-dev-server` config on `webpack.config.js`

   You should add this `historyApiFallback: true` to `devServer` on your webpack config.

   This will return index.html when 404.

   `devServer: {
       ...
       historyApiFallback: true
   }`
2. if you only use `cli`,do this

   `webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback`
3. if you use the node express `server.js`,see [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/145#issuecomment-170554832)

If production, you can edit the server config, make every request,return index.html, sure, exclude static files and api requst~

Sorry. I write this on mobile phone.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with  "make every request return index.html". I need to display the BoolPage and not the Home component

Comment: @JesterWest you must know, this is single page app.  the route change, make the page change, it operate only by js, not the server.   so ,when you first request the page( or refresh), the server give you the index.html, the next you change page only by js..             so, whether which page you need, the `index.html` and the js will give you~